# TracHours - total hours information lost

Tags: trac

I just realized that TracHours plugin accidentally turned off by itself.
After turning it back on all information about total hours in tickets is lost (is 0).

Did anyone ever come across such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a quick look and there doesn't seem to be a bug report about that happening. You should [file a bug report](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracHoursPlugin#BugsFeatureRequests).

TracHours saves its data both as a Trac custom field and in its own database table, `ticket_time`. If you have a backup of your database, you could just copy `ticket_time` and relevant rows of `ticket_custom` over.

Comment: Thanks. Finally decided to switch to JIRA. Trac sucks too much.

Comment: @Andrey: Just to defend Trac a little: the plugin interface is very easy to use, thus it's very easy to write plugins, thus it's very easy to write bad plugins. (And by bad I mean e.g. plugins that lose data.) I do think Trac core is quite excellent.

Comment: That would be OK if TracHours weren't the recommended plugin for time tracking.